# Error when getting variance decomp from SVAR in statsmodels

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, statsmodels, economics

I have set up an SVAR model with statsmodels.SVARResults. When I attempt to get the variance decomp it throws error or it just returns the memory location. I have tried two ways.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.api import VAR, SVAR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = DF[[various data fields]]



A = np.asarray([[1, 0, 0],[0, 1, 0],['E', 'E', 1]])
B = np.asarray([['E', 0, 0], [0, 'E', 0], [0, 0, 'E']])
A_guess = np.asarray([0.5, 0.25, -0.38])
B_guess = np.asarray([0.5, 0.1, 0.05])
mymodel = SVAR(df1, svar_type='AB', A=A, B=B)
res = mymodel.fit(maxlags=1, maxiter=10000, maxfun=10000, solver='bfgs')



res.fevd()
```

returns this error:

```
TypeError: irf() got an unexpected keyword argument 'var_decomp'
```

When I try it this way:

```
res.fevd
```

I simply get the memory location of the instance